# Cast pointer to reference_wrapper to pointer to underlying?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference-wrapper

Here's my situation:

I'm given data as a pointer say `double*`.

I want to wrap this in a `vector` to use a library, and to avoid messing around with pointers.

Not wanting to copy the entire array, I use a vector of reference wrappers. If I then want to get the `double*` back from said `vector` after using the library, can I get this by casting the `vector.data()` function?

For example:

```
double* arr = new double[10];
vector<reference_wrapper<const double> > vec(arr,arr+10);

//use library in some manner.

//is this allowed? is there a more appropriate way?
//or should I forget using reference_wrappers in this way.
double* res = (double*) vec.data()
```

Comment: A `std::reference_wrapper<const T>*` is *not* a `T*`. No amount of casting is going to change that.

Comment: This vector of reference wrappers looks doesn't buy you much. You are better off not afraiding to "mess around with pointers". If you don't have to manage lifetime of pointed-to objects, then *pointers are iterators*, no more and no less.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible.

`double` and `reference_wrapper<const double>` are completely unrelated types, there is no way to do this cast.

If you really need to manipulate C-style arrays, you should stick with `std::vector<double>`, and access the underlying array with the `data()` member function when needed.

Comment: I thought the library would require an `std::vector<double>` as input, not `std::vector<double*>`

Comment: OK. The answer is the same without const right? I guess I'll have to copy the array.

Comment: @retrocookie yes it is

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not true to say reference_wrapper<const double> isn't related to double. It defines operator const double&(); Therefore there is a valid deterministic path to converting one to a double*:
double* res3 = &const_cast<double&>(static_cast<const double&>(vec[0]));

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.

You can do this (but it's ugly):

```
double* arr = new double[10];
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>> vec(arr, arr + 10);

//use library in some manner.

//is this allowed? is there a more appropriate way?
//or should I forget using reference_wrappers in this way.
double* res = &vec[0].operator double &();
assert(res == arr);
```

I would forget using reference_wrapper like this and instead look at boost range:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html

Comment: Oh, it works.. I tried it on visual studio 2013. It's just not something to be recommended.